# Sorting a group of words inside a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm aware with sorting a list of list containing words by length.
Which means a list :

```
[[],['hello','indent'],['hi','monday'],['hi','low']]
```

which result if sorting key is length and reverse is True:

```
[['hello','indent','joe'],['hi','monday'],['hi','low'],[]]
```

But what i want is sort both by length and the ones having same length must be sorted in alphabetical order. i.e., 'low'<'monday' so output should be:

```
[['hello','indent','joe'],['hi','low'],['hi','monday'],[]]
```

Which kind of key must i use to sort using inbuilt sort?

EDIT: but what if the inputs are mixed case? What if it is:

`[['Hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]`

and the desired output will be :

```
[['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'monday'],['Hi', 'low'], []]
```

Comment: You should use the same `.sort()` it will implicitly generate the expected output I guess

Comment: Can you try making a custom function and pass it to `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single pass with a suitable key function.

```
a = [['hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]
a.sort(key=lambda l:(-len(l), l))
print a
```

**output**

```
[['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low'], ['hi', 'monday'], []]
```

---

To get lowercase letters to precede uppercase letters we can simply use the `str.swapcase()` method on the strings in each sub-list:

```
a = [['Hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]
a.sort(key=lambda l:(-len(l), [s.swapcase() for s in l]))
print a
```

**output**

```
[['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low'], ['Hi', 'monday'], []]
```

And if you want the sorting to be case-insensitive:

```
a = [['Hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]
a.sort(key=lambda l:(-len(l), [s.lower() for s in l]))
print a
```

**output**

```
[['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low'], ['Hi', 'monday'], []]
```

Comment: That seems to be perfect in case of lower case letter, but what if the inputs are mixed case? What if it is [['Hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']] and the desired output will be  :

[['hello', 'indent', 'joe'],  ['hi', 'monday'],['Hi', 'low'], []]

Comment: @galipremsagar: That's a little bit more complicated to do because uppercase letters precede lowercase letters in the default ASCII collation order. Eg, `ord('H')==72` and `ord('h')==104`. But luckily we can get around that with a simple trick.

Comment: What is that trick or key which sorts both by length of list and alphabetical sorting based on case-insensitive order?

Comment: @galipremsagar: I've added some code to my answer that illustrates the trick

Answer (score 1):

First sort by alphabetical order, then sort by length in reverse order.

```
>>> lst = [['hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
>>> print lst
>>> [['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low'], ['hi', 'monday'], []]
```

---

The order of items in the resulting set highly depends on your current **locale**. If you want your sort algorithm to take locale into account when sorting items, you can do the following;

```
>>> import locale
>>> from functools import cmp_to_key
>>>
>>> # You can change your locale like below;
>>> # locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
>>>
>>> lst = [['hi', 'monday'], [], ['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'low']]
>>> print sorted([sorted(item, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)) for item in lst], key=len, reverse=True)
>>> [['hello', 'indent', 'joe'], ['hi', 'monday'], ['hi', 'low'], []]
```